# Can't connect to a Windows 10 machine through RDP in Linux

Tags: linux, windows-10, networking, remote-desktop

I have configured Remote Desktop Connection on my Windows 10 as the windows below show

[image: Remote Connection Settings on Windows 10]

I even added the users I want to use to connect. I used one hotmail and one outlook account to do that

[image]

What happens is that now I have a notebook connected through VPN in the same network the windows machine I want to connect through RDP. This notebook is a Linux machine with Remmina. Then, after I input the IP of the remote machine, username, and password in my Linux Machine's Remmina, the window comes back and **keeps asking username and password**. This is the Remmina window that keeps appearing to me:

[image]

Below is the information about my PC:

[image]

The username I am trying to connect is in the same user list in the Windows allowed users list in the second window. I can login in Windows with it and also can access my Skype with the same username and password.

I am sure the users are valid and passwords are correct too. Is there anything I could fix in my windows PC to solve that issue?

Comment: What is the syntax you are using for the username.  If you are using a remote username you must specify the machine the username belongs to. Please edit your question and be as precise as possible, you can use a placeholder username, if you want to avoid revealing your actual username.

Comment: My username is my microsoft account: example myname@hotmail.com. Is there any other thing I must put in my username for rdp connection?

Comment: Please provide the exact syntax as an edit to your question.  Please specify the machine name of the Windows box in the same edit.

Comment: @Ramhound could you plese check my new Edit please?

Comment: Try replacing the email account name with this format (assuming you are using a Microsoft account): `MicrosoftAccount\email@domain.tld` or entering `MicrosoftAccount` in the client's "Domain" field. Sometimes RDP is very specific about the domain/realm that users use to connect.

Comment: Create a local account on the destination machine, grant it admin rights. When you connect add the machine name into the box labeled "Domain".

Comment: @SamForbis should I replace MicrosoftAccount field you told me with my username? should I put my-user-name@hotmail.com\email@domain.tld or MicrosoftAccount\my-user-name@hotmail.tld? I tried both and it is still failing. Thks

Comment: @Larryc I already have two local users with Admin rights. They are two Microsoft accounts (one outlook.com and another hotmail.com). I fail to log in with both.

Comment: @mad No, it should just read as `MicrosoftAccount\your-username@hotmail.com` or whatever you have your email address as. The "MicrosoftAccount" part tells the remote PC that you are trying to log in using a Microsoft account. As I mentioned, though, because the client has a "Domain" field, you may need to leave that out of the "Username" field and just put "MicrosoftAccount" in the domain field.

Comment: @SamForbis thank you, it is not working either :-( it seems the RDP server is not recognizing my password because it keeps asking it several times. Thanks anyway

Comment: @mad Only other suggestion I have is to check the Event Viewer logs on the Windows machine to see if you can glean any other information about why it isn't working. Those logs are located in Application and Services Logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager -> Operational

Comment: account@hotmail.com or account@outlook.com are not local accounts, it has to go to hotmail or outlook to verify credentials. When I say local account, I mean local to the host machine.

Comment: @Larryc - There are still local accounts that exist on the machine which can be used, the local accounts exist, using the local account and the current password should be more than enough to access the machine remotely.

Comment: @mad - In a elevated command prompt.  Provide the results of `%USERNAME%`

Comment: @Ramhound the echo %username% output is Utente. Thank you

Comment: @mad - `\MACHINENAME\Utente` should work, the syntax might be slightly off, don't have a test box in front of me